# How to generate IIS7 CSR (for SSL) from C# code or using Powershell on server which IIS is running

Tags: c#, iis-7, csr

How I can generate a server SSL Certificate Signing Request (CSR) from C#? If PowerShell is a better option, that would be a good solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general pointers:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382488%28VS.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382820%28VS.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/09/05/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-and-net-c.aspx
- http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis-7/

EDIT - as per comments:

The COM object [`CertEnroll`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/09/05/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-and-net-c.aspx) provided by MS can be accessed via PowerShell...

Comment: Actually my question is telling exactly what I need. I want to automate process of creating CSR for SSL certificates for software running on the same system where IIS server is running. URL:

Comment: I want to automate process of creating CSR for SSL certificates for software running on the same system where IIS server is running. URL:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/09/05/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-and-net-c.aspx

is closest to what I need but it uses COM objects. I was hoping to find something strictly C# or even from commandline (appcmd ...) but don't use COM objects.

Comment: AFAIK this is currently only possible via COM

Comment: I've updated my question with Powershell option. Maybe this way it could be possible?

Comment: Powershell can access the COM object... if that's what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's three years later, but the links in Yahia's solution state that they will not work for Server 2008.  Using PowerShell, I was able to use Certreq.exe, which ships with Server 2008, to generate the CSR.  The documentation for Certreq is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc725793.aspx), along with the full format for the INF file.  Of course, substitute your own values for the distinguished name.  The letters correspond to these fields:

- **CN**: Common Name
- **O**: Organization
- **OU**: Organizational Unit
- **L**: City/locality
- **S**: State/Province
- **C**: Country/region

The script assumes you have an environment variable named TEMP that points to a directory for which you have write access:

```
$reqFile = 'C:\ChangeMe\Request.req'
Push-Location $env:TEMP

@"
[NewRequest] 
Subject = "CN=www.contoso.com, O=Contoso Inc, OU=Sales, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
ProviderName = "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider"
KeyLength = 2048
MachineKeySet = true
FriendlyName = "www.contoso.com"
[RequestAttributes]
CertificateTemplate="WebServer"
"@ | Out-File .\request.inf -Encoding default -Force

certreq -f -new request.inf `"$reqFile`"
Pop-Location
```

For those who are new to PowerShell, the `@"` and `"@` delimiters must not be indented.  (These define what is known as a "Here-String"... more information [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx).)